# How To Apply Theme(Style, Color, Font) From Fragment to Whole Application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I tried to implement Theme from Activity it is done.

But in the Fragment it cannot Implemented.

I Used this :

```
getActivity().setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);
```

and also another method.
but I Can't get any proper Response please Help..☺

This is my Android Version.

[image]

Comment: Did you reload activity after setting theme?

Comment: Yes I Reload it, using recreate() function.